# SwiftUI Generic Type crashing

Tags: generics, swiftui

I'm experiencing strange behaviour using Generics in SwiftUI.

I have multiple structs, where all of them conform to CodelistProtocol containing "name" String variable

```
protocol CodelistProtocol: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var name: String { get set }
}
```

Sample:

```
struct ServiceTypeModel: CodelistProtocol, Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    ...
}
```

I have simple TagView struct to draw tags from the "names":

```
struct TagView<T: CodelistProtocol>: View {
    @Binding var tags: [T]

    private func generateContent() -> some View {
        ForEach(tags) { tag in
            Text(tag.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Calling TagView:

```
TagView<ServiceBenefitModel>(tags: $serviceCenterViewModel.serviceCenter.benefits)
```

The code above will crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

However, when I replace line

```
@Binding var tags: [T]
```

with

```
@Binding var tags: [ServiceTypeModel]
```

everything works flawlessly.

Comment: ranges are unsafe with SwiftUI, you can watch "Demystify SwiftUI"

Comment: experiencing the same issue, without ranges unfortunatelly

Comment: try let instead of binding (you don't need write access).